# Linking your app to an EXISTING page

Tags: facebook, web

I've searched and searched and can't seem to find any info in regards to this...

We have a facebook page (facebook.com/companyname). We also have an app on facebook (apps.facebook.com/companyname). I can create a NEW community page from the app, but i cant link it to the existing page. How come? Is there any way to do so?

There's plenty of similiar questions and no one has had an answer yet.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using existing Page as App page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791279/using-existing-page-as-app-page)

Comment: It is possible (I verified). Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265062/how-to-link-a-facebook-app-with-an-existing-fan-page#13904144

Answer (score 32):

You should go to edit your page and change the category to Brands & Products and sub-category to App Page.
Then go to app details and select this page as app page.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I just have an "Add Page" button in the new Apps interface, even though I switched the page to be an App Page.

Comment: The page and the app should have the same name

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me too.
Here are the more detailed steps that I followed:
* Go to your page, click 'About', then click 'Category' and as mentioned above select the 'Brands & Products' + App Page.
* Go to your App page, and click Settings (Advanced) and under the App Page section choose your existing page.

Comment: What if I don't have a "brands & products" option..?!

Answer (score 17):

@Muhammad Javeed - Thanks to you, I finally figured this out!

For those who need a little help, this was what I did.

1. Goto your existing Facebook Page
2. Click on 'Edit Page' button and select 'Edit Settings' from drop down menu.
3. Click on 'Page Info' on the settings page.
4. Click on 'Category' to expand selections.
5. Select 'Brands & Products' in 1st drop down and 'App Page' in the 2nd drop down.
6. Click 'Save Changes' and that's it.
7. Go back to your App Developer Page > App Details > Contact Info > App Page > Link to your Page.

Unless Facebook changes the menu/settings page dramatically, I can confirm this works!

Comment: I tried this today but did not work for me. I cannot find the page in App Page

Comment: Is it possible to link my application with an existing page created by another user ?

Comment: Just elaborating on this - for me to get it to work it seems that "App Page" must be the only category selected for the page, and the app name must exactly match the page name. Once the page has been associated, you can edit the page categories to whatever you want, and change the app name again if you wish.

Comment: @Mike is right, the 'app page' must be the only selected category.

Comment: @Mike Oh my god you are correct. You can even add whatever category you want later, but there must be only "App Page" category to connect an app with existing page. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I have done significant research into this. There is no way to do this (though it's such a common use case where someone already has an active fan page and launching an app later)

Earlier every app used to have a profile page (which was not like fan page) and facebook at the start of the year gave ever app admin to move their likes to another fan page. This option has been removed.

There is another way that I have discovered.

- Create fan page for the app (from app details section) by clicking "Create Fan Page"
- Goto pages and select this newly created fan page and rename it to be the same as the other active fan page(with which you initially wanted to link to). This is needed because merge option appear when 2 pages have same name and same category.
- Goto your active (original) fan page, click edit page, goto resource and click on merge pages and do the marge.

However as someone has already reported, there is a bug in the system, on merging it removes the app link (something that will be fixed soon). Here is the link to the bug.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/413029272079414?browse=search_5033475a2a50c9f73780526

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other answers but didn't worked for me.

What worked for my case is that I needed to make the name of the fb page & app's name match EXACTLY. And after making them the same I now see a dropdown and then selected the right fb page.

If you've linked them correctly you should see a new button called **"Play Now"** on your page, if its a game app.

Check it on this page

> https://www.facebook.com/pages/4-Pics-1-Word-Tagalog/499833986805671

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by:

1. Choose only one `App Page` for the page Category

[image]

2. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/ `Setting > Advanced`, scroll down to the App, now you can see the button to choose the existing page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a second Page on App Advance Settings.
Now go to the other first Page Settings you have and Merge.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this same issue. It appears that the name do not need to match entirely but at least the app name needs to start with (part of) the page name. I found this since the page name was longer than the allowed max name length of the app.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

as on Nov 17th, 2017.

App page itself is a category, selecting this category would be the only option.
Also, Fb App name and Fb Page name must be the same for integrating existing page.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about adding a tab for your app (apps.facebook.com/companyname) to your existing page (facebook.com/companyname)?

If so, then go to your page (facebook.com/companyname) and in the URL type in

"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[YOUR_APP_ID]&next=[YOUR_APP_CANVAS_URL]"

That should automatically direct to a form asking you which 'page' you would like to add a tab to. Select the page from the drop down list and click ok. That should redirect you to your app canvas url. Navigate back to your company page and see if the tab appears at the bottom of the list on the left hand side.

Cheers.

Comment: I mean, when you post something using your app, at the bottom it says via <app> - I want it so when you click the <app> it takes you to the page instead of the app. If that makes sense, Your response helped eliviate another one of my issues though!

Comment: Not working for me ... Error says `This application does not support integration with your profile`

Comment: Is this really the only way to do this? It seems crazy that you can't add an app to a page via some kind of UI

Comment: @codecowboy nope ... no luck, had to delete the page and start a new one.