# Using existing Page as App page

Tags: facebook

I've got a Facebook app created that is only used for authenticating Facebook Connect and mobile apps (i.e., it has no canvas URL or page tab, etc.). I want to set it up such that this app's page is an existing Facebook page, so that the "via " links when I share content point to this existing Facebook page (currently, it goes to an interstitial that says "You are being linked to the  web app", and redirects to our homepage).

If I look in the advanced settings, there is an "App Page" field, but the only option in that field is to create a new page—not the desired effect. Is there a way I can set this manually to an existing page?

P.S. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088381/linking-your-app-to-an-existing-page) showed up in the "similar questions"… it seems this person wanted the same thing I did, but never got a response. :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears as though you can now do this from the "App Details" tab of your Facebook App.

First ensure the following:

1. Your Facebook Page's category is set to Brands & Products/App Page
2. The name of your app and page match

If these two conditions are met, then you should see a dropdown menu with pages that you can associate with the app.

Comment: This solution still holds going into 2015... their Page Category seems like it needs a little work. Indeed - in my case - the page represents a Brand and Product, but now it doesn't associate properly to the category that best defines that product..

Comment: I can't find Brands & Products or App Page in categories in 2017?

Comment: In 2018, you need to change your app's category to `Business and Pages`, and the existing page is needed to be set `App Page` as its first category.

Comment: In 2021 There is no `App Page` category anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the chosen answer but it didn´t work.

The way I did it was this:

1. Categorize your existing page under "App Page" (found under "Brands & Products").
2. Change your page name to mach your App name.
3. Go to your App and select "App Details"
4. Under "Contact Info" you will find "App Page". There you will be able to create a new page or if all went well, select your page from a list.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904144/1598935

Regards!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a more-detailed version of the original answer. Thanks for fleshing it out for future searchers, though.

Comment: Does Brands & Products still exist?  I can't find it now that we're in 2017!

Comment: @Codemonkey Did you resolve this? I have an existing Brand page as well as an App ID. But I can't find a way to connect them.

Comment: Nope, I had no luck.